# Airbnb vs hostel near Manhattan. Is Aibnb very selective?

Tags: new-york-city, hostels, airbnb

I am looking for a hostel or a hostel alternative to stay in from Nov 11 - Nov 14th near Columbia. I noticed some good suggestions in a [previous thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8288/8918). Airbnb offers in the area are very competitive but *no one* seems to reply to my messages.

I am brand new to Airbnb, might that be the reason why?

If a newb has no place on Aibnb, which hostel or a hostel alternative would be a good place to sleep?

It's just a place to rest at night and have my suitcase (it will contain expensive research equipment from school) safe during the day when I am out exploring the city.

Comment: I think AirBnB in NYC is quite 'jeopardized' these days. You might read how AirBnB is considered illegal and how this law might be enforced : http://www.nbcnews.com/id/53282711/ns/local_news-new_york_ny/t/nyc-battles-short-term-rental-site

Comment: Let's start with questions on their own merit.  The fact that noone replies to your messages isn't answerable.  It depends on who you're writing to and what you're writing to them.  As for the 2nd question it's too broad for the place like New York because near Manhattan covers pretty wide range of options.  Including those in New Jersey which is not doesn't have an issue with AirBNB.

Comment: @Karlson: Thanks. I will rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vince mentioned AirBnb right now is having a little problem in New York that's why you got some difficulties. My friend just came back from New York and he chose AirBnB without any problem three months ago before AirBnb filed a motion to the supreme court. http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/09/airbnb-ny-supreme-court/. I think that might be why you got no response. Also, one of things that you didn't get a response might be that people you asked have low response rate. Have you checked that? You can check that form the listing.

To answer the second question. I have been using this site to search hostels around the world. http://www.hostelworld.com/search?search_keywords=New+York%2C+USA&country=USA&city=New-York&date_from=2013-10-31&date_to=2013-11-03 And I never got problems finding reasonable hostels to stay.